# Induction step in an argument of Stroock and Varadhan 1979

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability

**Question** On page 298 of Multidimensional Diffusion proceses of Stroock and Varadhan 
[image]

I believe it should be

$$ S^{m+1}_\lambda f(z,x) = \lambda \Bbb{E}^{P^{\alpha_m(z)}_x}\big[\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda s}S^{m}_\lambda f(z, x(s))\, ds\big] $$

**Context:** Important to the question are the following:
[image]

and

[image]

Is this a typo? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There is no typo, see

[image]

The counting is made backwards